# Boost error codes reference

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Does anyone know where to find a reference for boost error codes. In particular, error codes returned by asynchronous socket handlers?, Google and grepping the header files have tuned up empty.

Comment: I don't know boost, but if you are lucky, you may get the same error codes as what is in `errno.h`. On Linux, it's `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` and `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`), see http://lxr.linux.no/linux/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h and http://lxr.linux.no/linux/include/asm-generic/errno.h .

Comment: is your question resolved now?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I got sidetracked. The error codes are derived from the system codes. For Windows these can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28VS.85%29.aspx. For linux, the main header is /usr/incude/errno.h. Note that you'll have to do a little digging on linux as the actual codes are stored in a more obscure file, such as /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I extracted the error values from asio/error.hpp on Linux (I'm using header only asio not boost::asio by the way), here they are:

```
asio::error::access_denied 13
asio::error::address_family_not_supported 97
asio::error::address_in_use 98
asio::error::already_connected 106
asio::error::already_started 114
asio::error::broken_pipe 32
asio::error::connection_aborted 103
asio::error::connection_refused 111
asio::error::connection_reset 104
asio::error::bad_descriptor 9
asio::error::fault 14
asio::error::host_unreachable 113
asio::error::in_progress 115
asio::error::interrupted 4
asio::error::invalid_argument 22
asio::error::message_size 90
asio::error::name_too_long 36
asio::error::network_down 100
asio::error::network_reset 102
asio::error::network_unreachable 101
asio::error::no_descriptors 24
asio::error::no_buffer_space 105
asio::error::no_memory 12
asio::error::no_permission 1
asio::error::no_protocol_option 92
asio::error::not_connected 107
asio::error::not_socket 88
asio::error::operation_aborted 125
asio::error::operation_not_supported 95
asio::error::shut_down 108
asio::error::timed_out 110
asio::error::try_again 11
asio::error::would_block 11
```

If you want to generate your own list, this should save you a few mins of copying and pasting:

```
std::cout << "asio::error::access_denied " << asio::error::access_denied << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::address_family_not_supported " << asio::error::address_family_not_supported << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::address_in_use " << asio::error::address_in_use << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::already_connected " << asio::error::already_connected << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::already_started " << asio::error::already_started << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::broken_pipe " << asio::error::broken_pipe << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::connection_aborted " << asio::error::connection_aborted << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::connection_refused " << asio::error::connection_refused << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::connection_reset " << asio::error::connection_reset << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::bad_descriptor " << asio::error::bad_descriptor << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::fault " << asio::error::fault << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::host_unreachable " << asio::error::host_unreachable << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::in_progress " << asio::error::in_progress << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::interrupted " << asio::error::interrupted << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::invalid_argument " << asio::error::invalid_argument << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::message_size " << asio::error::message_size << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::name_too_long " << asio::error::name_too_long << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::network_down " << asio::error::network_down << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::network_reset " << asio::error::network_reset << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::network_unreachable " << asio::error::network_unreachable << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::no_descriptors " << asio::error::no_descriptors << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::no_buffer_space " << asio::error::no_buffer_space << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::no_memory " << asio::error::no_memory << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::no_permission " << asio::error::no_permission << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::no_protocol_option " << asio::error::no_protocol_option << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::not_connected " << asio::error::not_connected << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::not_socket " << asio::error::not_socket << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::operation_aborted " << asio::error::operation_aborted << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::operation_not_supported " << asio::error::operation_not_supported << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::shut_down " << asio::error::shut_down << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::timed_out " << asio::error::timed_out << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::try_again " << asio::error::try_again << std::endl;
std::cout << "asio::error::would_block " << asio::error::would_block << std::endl;
```

Comment: For those who may wonder why both `asio::error::try_again` and `asio::error::would_block` have the same value (11), read e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom, specifically the section EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK: "..POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case..".

Comment: If you get error code 2, which is not included in this list, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782429/what-is-boost-system-error-code-number-2.

Answer (score 7):

you most likely want

```
#include <boost/asio/errors.hpp>
```

it is included in the asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html).

Comment: `Cannot open include file: 'boost/asio/errors.hpp': No such file or directory` Are you sure about this? I use boost 1.55 and it does not work. Other asio includes cause no problem.

Comment: In Modular Boost (my version is 1.6.1) the file "error_codes.hpp" is in boost/system. The error codes are all defined in an enumeration, but most of them are assigned values from existing macros, e.g. address_family_not_supported=EAFNOSUPPORT. These macros are supplemented by "boost/cerrno.hpp", but should be defined by your system's "errno.h", "/usr/include/asm/errno.h". The values appear to be standardized across Unix/Linux systems, which means they're easy enough to look up, but AFAIK/understand the Boost definitions are partly there to eliminate this kind of drudgery. Does that help?

Comment: In the documentation, the error codes are not given.

Answer (score 1):

there is no file "boost/asio/errors.hpp" but you shoud add "boost/asio/error.hpp" in include file