# What is boost system error_code number 2

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, system

I am trying to figure out what boost system error code 2 is.  Within a program they print out the boost error code.  However, I am not sure how to look up this error code.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head: ENOENT/FileNotFound

See the errorcodes in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html#Header-error_code

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65a0d25ce86c4480)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    ec.assign(2, boost::system::system_category());
    std::cout << ec.message() << "\n";

    ec.assign(boost::system::errc::no_such_file_or_directory, boost::system::system_category());
    std::cout << ec.message() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
No such file or directory
No such file or directory
```

Comment: now I need to understand why the hell I get it on Mac no matter what boost filesystem operation I call :(

Comment: @SridharSarnobat uisng the crystal ball, your current working directory might not be what you think it is

Comment: I tried everything and gave up. In the end I ended up using stat.h which doesn't feel like proper C++ but I'll post another question if I wish to feel more frustrated.

Comment: Well that's interesting because in my experience error 2 is `End of File`. (In my case, other end cleanly closed the connection) On further investigation `ec.category().name()` returns `asio.misc` so that explains the difference. So if the program the OP mentioned was outputting the error code but *not* the category, then its impossible to know. Though it does narrow it down a lot.

Comment: @Rodney Yes, in general, don't compare `error_code::value()` "ever". They don't mean anything in isolation. Always prefer to compare the entire object, or better yet: error conditions: [e.g. live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e357466c10b96e3c) Recently Boost System added interoperability with std error categories. There really is no reason left to deal with the internals. See also the excellent new documentation: [Testing For Specific Error Conditions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#usage_testing_for_specific_error_conditions)

Answer (score 1):

For windows it is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Check the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)